# Downloading files >3Gb from S3 fails with "SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out"

Tags: java, amazon-s3, socket-timeout-exception

AWS Java SDK 1.9.3

When downloading many large files (~3Gb) from AWS S3 in Java server app I get SocketTimeoutException from time to time as following:

```
Caused by: com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to store object contents to disk: Read timed out
 at com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.ServiceUtils.downloadObjectToFile(ServiceUtils.java:270)
 at com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.ServiceUtils.retryableDownloadS3ObjectToFile(ServiceUtils.java:344)
 at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.TransferManager$2.call(TransferManager.java:737)
 ... 4 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
 at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
 at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:152)
 at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
 at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:442)
 at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readV3Record(InputRecord.java:554)
 at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:509)
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:927)
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:884)
 at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:102)
 at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.read(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:198)
 at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthInputStream.read(ContentLengthInputStream.java:178)
 at org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.read(EofSensorInputStream.java:137)
 at com.amazonaws.internal.SdkFilterInputStream.read(SdkFilterInputStream.java:73)
 at com.amazonaws.event.ProgressInputStream.read(ProgressInputStream.java:151)
 at com.amazonaws.internal.SdkFilterInputStream.read(SdkFilterInputStream.java:73)
 at com.amazonaws.internal.SdkFilterInputStream.read(SdkFilterInputStream.java:73)
 at com.amazonaws.internal.SdkFilterInputStream.read(SdkFilterInputStream.java:73)
 at com.amazonaws.event.ProgressInputStream.read(ProgressInputStream.java:151)
 at java.security.DigestInputStream.read(DigestInputStream.java:161)
 at com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.DigestValidationInputStream.read(DigestValidationInputStream.java:59)
 at com.amazonaws.internal.SdkFilterInputStream.read(SdkFilterInputStream.java:73)
 at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107)
 at com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.ServiceUtils.downloadObjectToFile(ServiceUtils.java:265)
 ... 6 more
```

I download files from S3 using 4 threads, all threads use the same TransferManager instance. As mantioned before, I'm using AWS SDK 1.9.3 and get such exceptions only from time to time. Code is the following:

```
...
Download d = transferManager.download(currentBucket, remoteFileName, new File(tmpName));
d.waitForCompletion();
...
```

Is it an issue of SDK? Maybe of v1.9.3?

And is there any solution except increasing `socketTimeout` for `ClientConfiguration`?

Comment: I'm having the same problem.
I'm using AWS S3 Android SDK 2.1.7, and my files have about 10MB.
Did you got an answer to solve it?

Comment: Still no solution for this issue except changing timeouts.

Comment: Hi @Yury, can you, please, show me how to change timeouts?

Comment: Hi @Caaarlos. Here is how I can do in AWS SDK 1.9.3:
`ClientConfiguration config = new ClientConfiguration();
config.setConnectionTimeout(connectionTimeout);
config.setSocketTimeout(readTimeout);
AmazonS3 s3 = new AmazonS3Client(credentials, config);`

Comment: @Yury can you post your solution as an official Answer to this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is how I can do in AWS SDK 1.9.3:

```
ClientConfiguration config = new ClientConfiguration(); 
config.setConnectionTimeout(connectionTimeout);
config.setSocketTimeout(readTimeout); 
AmazonS3 s3 = new AmazonS3Client(credentials, config);
```

Comment: What's the default timeout?

Comment: the default timeout as in 1.10.x is 50s for both socket and connection timeouts.

Comment: I'd love to see a v2 version of this!