# AWS SWF Decider 'java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out' when polling

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-swf, socket-timeout-exception

I'm encountering this error whenever my SWF Worker application polls. If there's an entry in the SWF queue, it gets processed properly. But if it's empty, this timeout exception is returned.

```
com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient      : Unable to execute HTTP request: Read timed out

java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:150) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
        at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
        at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:961) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:918) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
        at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:105) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.streamRead(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:139) ~[httpcore-4.4.4.jar!/:4.4.4]
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.fillBuffer(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:155) ~[httpcore-4.4.4.jar!/:4.4.4]
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.readLine(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:284) ~[httpcore-4.4.4.jar!/:4.4.4]
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:140) ~[httpclient-4.5.1.jar!/:4.5.1]
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:57) ~[httpclient-4.5.1.jar!/:4.5.1]
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:261) ~[httpcore-4.4.4.jar!/:4.4.4]
        at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:165) ~[httpcore-4.4.4.jar!/:4.4.4]
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:167) ~[httpclient-4.5.1.jar!/:4.5.1]
        at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:272) ~[httpcore-4.4.4.jar!/:4.4.4]
        at com.amazonaws.http.protocol.SdkHttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(SdkHttpRequestExecutor.java:82) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.22.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:124) ~[httpcore-4.4.4.jar!/:4.4.4]
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:271) ~[httpclient-4.5.1.jar!/:4.5.1]
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184) ~[httpclient-4.5.1.jar!/:4.5.1]
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184) ~[httpclient-4.5.1.jar!/:4.5.1]
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82) ~[httpclient-4.5.1.jar!/:4.5.1]
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55) ~[httpclient-4.5.1.jar!/:4.5.1]
        at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.SdkHttpClient.execute(SdkHttpClient.java:72) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.22.jar!/:na]
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:880) [aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.22.jar!/:na]
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:723) [aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.22.jar!/:na]
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:475) [aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.22.jar!/:na]
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:437) [aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.22.jar!/:na]
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:386) [aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.22.jar!/:na]
        at com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.AmazonSimpleWorkflowClient.doInvoke(AmazonSimpleWorkflowClient.java:3133) [aws-java-sdk-simpleworkflow-1.11.22.jar!/:na]
        at com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.AmazonSimpleWorkflowClient.invoke(AmazonSimpleWorkflowClient.java:3103) [aws-java-sdk-simpleworkflow-1.11.22.jar!/:na]
        at com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.AmazonSimpleWorkflowClient.pollForDecisionTask(AmazonSimpleWorkflowClient.java:1967) [aws-java-sdk-simpleworkflow-1.11.22.jar!/:na]
        at com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.worker.DecisionTaskPoller.poll(DecisionTaskPoller.java:171) [aws-java-sdk-swf-libraries-1.11.22.jar!/:na]
        at com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.worker.DecisionTaskPoller.access$0(DecisionTaskPoller.java:158) [aws-java-sdk-swf-libraries-1.11.22.jar!/:na]
        at com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.worker.DecisionTaskPoller$DecisionTaskIterator.<init>(DecisionTaskPoller.java:44) [aws-java-sdk-swf-libraries-1.11.22.jar!/:na]
        at com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.worker.DecisionTaskPoller.pollAndProcessSingleTask(DecisionTaskPoller.java:197) [aws-java-sdk-swf-libraries-1.11.22.jar!/:na]
        at com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.worker.GenericWorker$PollServiceTask.run(GenericWorker.java:94) [aws-java-sdk-swf-libraries-1.11.22.jar!/:na]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_31]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_31]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_31]
```

What's causing this?

I'm using this setup:

```
@Workflow
@WorkflowRegistrationOptions(
        defaultExecutionStartToCloseTimeoutSeconds = 259200, //3 days
        defaultTaskStartToCloseTimeoutSeconds = 180
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens when HTTP client socket timeout is less than 61 seconds. Long poll doesn't return up to 60 seconds and 
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out is thrown.

Use [ClientConfiguration.setSocketTimeout](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/ClientConfiguration.html#setSocketTimeout-int-) to change the timeout. This structure is passed to [AmazonSimpleWorkflowClient](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/simpleworkflow/AmazonSimpleWorkflowClient.html) constructor. Looking at AmazonSimpleWorkflowClient [implementation](https://github.com/puppetlabs/aws-sdk-for-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/simpleworkflow/AmazonSimpleWorkflowClient.java#L511) it should default to 90 seconds if not set. So make sure that you are using the latest client and the timeout is set correctly.

Comment: Got an idea how to set client socket timeout?

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: Thanks! Although, isn't 50 secs the default for the latest version? https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/aws-java-sdk-core/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/ClientConfiguration.java

Comment: I remember that Simple Workflow Client was somehow adjusting it to the correct value. I wouldn't be surprised that some of the new releases broke that.